# array_walk only leaving values?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
array_walk(
    array('foo' => 2, 'bar' => 5, ...),
    function ($v, $k) { return $k . '=' . $v; }
);
```

But after this, all thats left is `array(2, 5)`.

Why is this the case and how do I get the expected result of `array('foo=2', 'bar=5')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass your value by reference, like

```
$rgData = array('foo' => 2, 'bar' => 5);
array_walk(
    $rgData,
    function (&$v, $k) { $v = $k . '=' . $v; }
);
```

Also note that referenced value itself should be changed (return is not necessary here, only `$v` changing matters)